# Applying two training data sets to model.fit or combining the results of two Image Generator function for our CNN model

Tags: image-processing

Does anyone know how we can apply two training data sets into the Model.fit section of our CNN model?

I can ask my question in another way, I am applying some augmentation strategies to my images using the Imagedata generator function in Kers to increase the number of my training data. I am wondering if there is a straightforward way that we can combine the results of two Image generator function without saving into directories and then use them in our model?

'''train_batches1 = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255).flow_from_directory(directory="/content/gdrive/Shareddrives/Yihai, Brandon and Mostafa (1)/Images/Cross validation/Fold1/Train",target_size=(64,64),classes=['Normal','OR21_6','OR7_6','OR14_6','OR7_12','OR7_3','OR21_3','OR21_12'],batch_size=10)

train_batches2 = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,horizontal_flip=True).flow_from_directory(directory="/content/gdrive/Shareddrives/Yihai, Brandon and Mostafa (1)/Images/Cross validation/Fold1/Train",target_size=(64,64),classes=['Normal','OR21_6','OR7_6','OR14_6','OR7_12','OR7_3','OR21_3','OR21_12'],batch_size=10)'''

With best regards,
Mostafa.

Comment: Both generators are the same but with different augmentation.right?

Comment: Yes the first one simply rescale the pixel values to 0 to 1 and the second generator in addition to rescaling, horizontally flips the pixel values. I want to use the results of the two generators as an input to my CNN model.

Answer (score 0):

You want rescale all the images(repeat dataset twice) and flip half of them
Use only one augmentation process for your data. You can use the `imgaug` library. it's like Keras sequential models that image flows in it.

```py
import numpy as np
import imgaug as ia
import imgaug.augmenters as iaa


# Define our sequence of augmentation steps that will be applied to every image
# All augmenters with per_channel=0.5 will sample one value _per image_
# in 50% of all cases. In all other cases they will sample new values
# _per channel_.

seq = iaa.Sequential(
    [
        # apply the following augmenters to most images

        iaa.Fliplr(0.5), # horizontally flip 50% of all images
      
        
]
```

You can add any kind of augmentation you need in this sequential.
And set your augmentation function equal to `seq` and repeat your dataset.

Comment: Thank you Sadegh for your time.